How to make the background image stop overflowing
I want the image to not overflow and expand my webpage. I tried overflow:hidden in some places but still doesnt work.
I added a ::after because I don't want the text to zoom as well.


.mainScreen {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mainScreen::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/9707969/pexels-photo-9707969.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: zoom-in-zoom-out 30s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom-in-zoom-out {
  /*This is the animation zoom-in-zoom-out effect*/
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
<div class="mainScreen">
</div>




overflow: hidden;
position: relative; add this 2 class in mainScreen

Try using background-size instead and you can put the image on the main element.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.mainScreen {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/9707969/pexels-photo-9707969.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top center;
  animation: zoom-in-zoom-out 30s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom-in-zoom-out {
  /*This is the animation zoom-in-zoom-out effect*/
  0% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 110% auto;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
}
<div class="mainScreen"></div>




It worked,thank you so much
